# Login using face-id in cognitive service

Tags: face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am developing App for login and registration using cognitive face api but when i use detect Face API call then i get face-id but it's expire after **24 hr**. Is there any solution for that,I want a face-id which will not expire for lifetime or let me know the flow how we will do device independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FaceList - Add Face to get a persistedFaceId. The face image and related info will be stored on server until FaceList - Delete Face or FaceList - Delete is called.

Comment: thanks...
Yes i got persisted face-id but i want to know how to get accuracy in findsimilar call or is there any other way to verify current face-id with stored Persisted-Id in FaceList